# Upsert in node.js - what is `IF EXIST`?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Could someone explain the if exist command that is used in SQL?

for example:

```
if exist(select * from waiter){
    update waiter set (...) where waiter_id='somevalue'
} else{
    insert into waiter values (values)
}
```

Could you also explain how one will check if the update/insert was completed without going into the database?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name postgres

Comment: [*The subquery is evaluated to determine whether it returns any rows. If it returns at least one row, the result of EXISTS is "true"; if the subquery returns no rows, the result of EXISTS is "false".*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about just reading the documentation

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Please do not reffer to the manual of outdated versions. Use `/docs/current/static/` instead of `/docs/8.1/static/` in links to postgres documentation

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko Missed that the link was versioned. Just grabbed what appeared in a search. But, updated the link.

Comment: The above code is nonsense, it can never run in PostgreSQL because there's no `IF test { block } else { block }` statement, either in SQL or (with that syntax) in PL/PgSQL. It's also clear that you're attempting to do an upsert, and this is a totally incorrect way to do an upsert. See horse's link, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-do-i-do-an-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql/17267423#17267423

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this helps, but the code should probably read:

```
if exist(select * from waiter where waiter_id='somevalue') {
    update waiter set (...) where waiter_id='somevalue'
} else{
    insert into waiter values (values)
}
```

The `if exists . . .` portion in this case is saying "if the record exists in the table".  Overall, the statement is saying "if the `'somevalue'` record exists in the value, then update the record; otherwise, insert a new record."

Comment: Good find on the missing `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud . . . "If the tables isn't empty, do an update on a record that might or might not exist, otherwise insert a record" doesn't seem like a sensible or safe thing to do.  ;)

Comment: @Gordon Linoff now what about if I was to see if this happened? How will I know? for example how will I know if the update or the insert has happened without looking into the database?

Comment: @user3192435 . . . The easiest thing to do is to set a variable inside each clause and then examine the variable afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

The approach you are taking is wrong. It will not work. Stop.

Go read the guidance on upserts:

- [Insert, on duplicate update in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-postgresql)
- [How to UPSERT (MERGE, INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE) in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-do-i-do-an-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql/17267423#17267423)

and then use one of the *correct* methods documented there, either locking the table and doing the upsert, or doing it in a retry loop.

To understand why your current approach is wrong, think about what happens when two people do the same command at the same time.

- person1: `select * from waiter`
- person2: `select * from waiter`
- person1: `if exist(...)` => false, nope, doesn't exist
- person2: `if exist(...)` => false, nope, doesn't exist
- person1: `insert...`
- person2: `insert...`

and **boom, you have two records**.

(This approach is also awfully inefficient - the `SELECT * FROM WAITER` is just horrible).

That's why everyone's giving you links to articles and documentation showing you how to do it right. You're trying to solve the wrong problem. You're effectively saying "When I drive my car into the intersection without looking at the traffic lights, how do I know if somebody else is already there?". We're saying "Uh, don't do that. Look at the traffic lights."

Only once you have the actual upsert ("create if not exists") operation correct, *then* worry about how to deal with it from node.js.

I'd say it'll be like any other query, anyway: Run query/command, get id (either existing or newly created) as result from query, use ID however you want. If you need more help with that part, try posting a node.js specific question on just that part, without all the incorrect-upsert-code mess to throw everybody off track. Consider that many on the [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) tag won't know much about node.js anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The `exists` statement do a partial scan over the sql to know if something was returned..

If we was check the perform about `exists` if comparated with count().. we would see a really faster sql using exists, since count will go check each row at the database.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Now what id I want to check if the update/insert has been completed without looking into the database? @Hugo S. Mendes

Comment: then you need to put the  "where waiter_id='somevalue'" into the exists like this: exist(select * from waiter where waiter_id='somevalue')